# How do I make a follow-up form private in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I want to send an email to customers that allows them to edit some of the information for their purchase, so my basic set-up is sending them a link to /follow_up_form/purchase.id.

This clearly won't work because we don't want anyone just typing in that URL and changing the user's information, but our site doesn't have any login necessary to make purchases.

Is there a way to autogenerate a secret URL, or pass through some sort of authenticity token? This feels like it should be simple but I don't have any good ideas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may use rails 5 [has_secure_token](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SecureToken/ClassMethods.html) and embed it into an URL as a parameter like  /follow_up_form/purchase.id?tok='some_toke' And check this parameter when returning the form for edition. This will indeed make stuff more secure.

Comment: thanks, i should have mentioned I'm using Rails 4 but I accomplished something similar with the BCrypt Gem.

Comment: BCrypt is totally overkill - its meant to encrypt passwords with a relativly high computing cost. Just use the Ruby stdlib [SecureRandom](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html). `has_secure_token` uses `SecureRandom.base58(24)`. The chance of collision is almost nil.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a `token` column to the purchase, and set it after creation:

```
require 'secure_random'
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :regenerate_token

  def regenerate_token
    self.token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(24)
  end
end
```

You can then setup follow ups just like you would any other nested resource:

```
resources :purchases do
  resources :follow_ups, only: [:new, :create]
end
```

To create a link to the form where the user gives feedback use:

```
<%= link_to("Tell us what you think", new_purchase_follow_up_url(@purchase, token: @purchase.token)) %>
```

This adds an query string parameter to the URL containing the access token.
To authenticate in the controller we check if the access token matches what we  have stored for the purchase:

```
class FollowUpsController < ApplicationConrtroller
  before_action :set_purchase!
  before_action :check_token!

  # ...

  private 
    def set_purchase!
      @purchase = Purchase.find(params[:purchase_id])
    end

    def check_token!
      unless params[:access_token] == @purchase.token
        redirect_to root_path, error: 'You are not authorized' and return false
      end
    end
end
```

To pass the token between the new and create action add it to the form as a hidden input:

```
<%= form_for(@follow_up) do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :access_token, @purchase.token %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This is pretty much a straight backport of [has_secure_token](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SecureToken/ClassMethods.html) except that I use `urlsafe_base64` which ensures the token is suited  to be included in the query string.